# What does $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{n^x}{x^n}$ converge to when $x\in\mathbb R^+$ and $x>1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> What does $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{n^x}{x^n}$ converge to when $x\in\mathbb R^+$ and $x>1$?

I'm looking for a hint of how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition of the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) this is :
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^{*}}\frac{n^x}{x^n}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^{*}}\frac{\left(\frac 1x\right)^n}{n^{-x}}=\operatorname{Li}_{-x}\left(\frac 1x\right)$$

This simplifies for non negative integer values of $x$ (and $-1$) as seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values).